# C# TCP Client listening for data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client, listen

I would like to connect to a specific barcode reader at my work but currently I'm facing some problems to understand how TCP stream reading works with C#.

I've looked for many code samples on stackoverflow and as I can see, people oftenly open a connection, send a command and then ask for the reply.

The point is, the barcode reader just accept a TCP connection and then send the data with my data.

I would like find the most efficient way to use TcpClient or NetworkStream to read in a continuous way the data. I mean, I would like to listen for the data when it's incoming but also process many other things at the same time I'm listening.

I was wonderning if simple TCP libraries exists like a one with a Connect function, and an event firing when you receive data (with a delimiter or with a length).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a simple TCP library called [SimpleTCP](https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP). I'm able to connect to my network barcode reader with the following line of code: `g_Client.Connect(ip, port);`

Then there is an event available called DataReceived (`g_Client.DataReceived += l_Client_DataReceived;)` which allow me to do exactly what I want.

This library also gives access to the TcpClient it's using and I'm currently searching for the possibility to see the special characters such as < STX >(currently returning me a special char in ASCII) but I will have to do another thread for this I think.

Answer (score 0):

TCP doesn't sound right, but if it is it might be acting as a http server.If it is then you'd use a HttpClient. If it is just TCP, you would do something like:[Async Client Socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx)